# Share (masquerade) Internet connection from Debian desktop to a bunch of computers

Tags: debian, networking, ip, connection-sharing

I need to share the Internet connection of my Debian desktop to some other devices (a  Mac Laptop, and an Android tablet).

The Debian desktop is connected to the local network via `eth0`, and the rest of the devices are connected through a wireless network which, for some reason, doesn't allow internet connections. Of course, the desktop is connected to the internet.

The laptop and the tablet *can* "see" the Debian desktop (they can connect themselves through `ssh` and see the desktop files using `smb`).

I've been googling around, and I've found how to share (masquerade) the connection and make it available to any machine in the network... I would like to limit the access only to my devices (or a limited list of devices).

Is there a way to do that? If there is, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: With Ubuntu, anyway (and therefore probably Debian), you can set up a computer as a wifi hotspot if it has wifi & is connected to the network *not* using wifi (ie, using eth0). You could try to google for "Ubuntu (or Debian) hotspot wifi", & see if any of these work for Debian...

Comment: The desktop does not have WiFi (I tried to install an USB Wireless LAN adapter on it, without success :( )